# Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

1. Description: An unhanded exception occurred during the execution of
   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

   Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
   file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. The
   system cannot find the file specified.

   Source Error:

   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location
   of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
   below.

   Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
   determine why the assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' could not be loaded.

   === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5 
   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/Working
   File/V1/V1/InfraERP/Infra.AuditWS/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
   E:\Working File\V1\V1\InfraERP\Infra.AuditWS\bin Calling assembly :
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\Working
   File\V1\V1\InfraERP\Infra.AuditWS\web.config LOG: Using host
   configuration file:
   C:\Users\Infra04\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
   Using machine configuration file from
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
   LOG: Post-policy reference: Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5 LOG: Attempting download of new URL
   file:///C:/Users/Infra04/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
   Files/root/b2eb5b6f/c83c34d7/Owin.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of
   new URL file:///C:/Users/Infra04/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary
   ASP.NET Files/root/b2eb5b6f/c83c34d7/Owin/Owin.DLL. LOG: Attempting
   download of new URL file:///E:/Working
   File/V1/V1/InfraERP/Infra.AuditWS/bin/Owin.DLL. LOG: Attempting
   download of new URL file:///E:/Working
   File/V1/V1/InfraERP/Infra.AuditWS/bin/Owin/Owin.DLL. LOG: Attempting
   download of new URL
   file:///C:/Users/Infra04/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
   Files/root/b2eb5b6f/c83c34d7/Owin.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of
   new URL file:///C:/Users/Infra04/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary
   ASP.NET Files/root/b2eb5b6f/c83c34d7/Owin/Owin.EXE. LOG: Attempting
   download of new URL file:///E:/Working
   File/V1/V1/InfraERP/Infra.AuditWS/bin/Owin.EXE. LOG: Attempting
   download of new URL file:///E:/Working
   File/V1/V1/InfraERP/Infra.AuditWS/bin/Owin/Owin.EXE.

   Stack Trace:

   [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Owin,
   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5'
   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
   specified.]
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
   +0    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   +115    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
   context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172 
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
   appContext) +296

   [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Owin,
   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5'
   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
   specified.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
   context) +9963856

Comment: could you explain more background information instead of dumping the stacktrace..? like, what you want to do, how you install the dependencies.. is it NuGet? (if so, perhaps reinstalling your dependencies and rebuild the project will solve it)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please change in the line "bindingRedirect " your web.config if your version of microsoft.owin is 3.0.0


<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" /> 
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: After adding above code error is not resolve . Current Error:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I have updated  bindingRedirect  portion in my answer.can you please retry with current answer.